# Rails technology selection for a hybrid e-commerce/subscription solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am looking to build a Rails application with a few main features, and am having trouble deciding which approach to take to build the most flexible and scalable system.  The core features are:

1)  Users can subscribe for products (i.e., monthly billing).
2)  Users can purchase individual products
3)  The system has full blog/static content capabilities for administrators

The core of the business is subscriptions, so I am thinking of building the app using the Stripe API for subscriptions, building the admin section, user account features, and static pages & blog from scratch in the rails app, and then adding in Spree Commerce for the individual product purchasing.

Is this is a good approach to this problem, or would I be better off building the app itself in Spree (using their extensions for static content and blogging capabilities), and then adding in the custom subscriptions with Stripe ontop of that?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Spree very much assumes a classic order workflow. A Product, ProductInstance which belongs_to an Order, and a Payment that belongs_to an Order.

With some hacking, you may be able to get recurring payments, but it won't be ideal. subscriptions are Recurring payments, in essence. However, Stripe has perfect support for subscriptions, so if you choose to not handle any of it in Spree, and leave the initial order+payment to spree and then handle everything in Stripe, it may work.